# I can't delete empty containers in an xml document on SQL Server, such as "<Item />"

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014

I started working for the first time and I don't know much yet, I've been suffering with this problem for two days.

I have a document of this type:

```
<Tables>
  <dbo.ES_Connection_Modes>
    <Item />
  </dbo.ES_Connection_Modes>
  <dbo.ES_Device_Categories>
    <Item>
      <LINK>1</LINK>
      <F_Class>1</F_Class>
      <N_Code>1</N_Code>
      <B_Default>1</B_Default>
      <B_Meter>1</B_Meter>
      <B_Tranf>0</B_Tranf>
      <B_Regist>0</B_Regist>
      <B_Show_InMenu>1</B_Show_InMenu>
      <N_Project>-1</N_Project>
      <C_Const>EDC_Meter</C_Const>
    </Item>
  </dbo.ES_Device_Categories>
  <dbo.ES_Indicating_Device_Types>
    <Item />
  </dbo.ES_Indicating_Device_Types>
  <dbo.ES_Operating_Principles>
    <Item />
  </dbo.ES_Operating_Principles>
  <dbo.ES_Precission_Classes>
    <Item>
      <LINK>7</LINK>
      <N_Project>687783</N_Project>
      <C_Name>2,0</C_Name>
      <C_Const>EPC_20</C_Const>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <LINK>8</LINK>
      <N_Project>687783</N_Project>
      <C_Name>2,5</C_Name>
      <C_Const>EPC_25</C_Const>
    </Item>
  </dbo.ES_Precission_Classes>
  <dbo.ES_Granularity>
    <Item />
  </dbo.ES_Granularity>
</Tables>
```

I need to delete the empty item containers and the container containing it to get a document of the following type:

```
<Tables>
  <dbo.ES_Device_Categories>
    <Item>
      <LINK>1</LINK>
      <F_Class>1</F_Class>
      <N_Code>1</N_Code>
      <B_Default>1</B_Default>
      <B_Meter>1</B_Meter>
      <B_Tranf>0</B_Tranf>
      <B_Regist>0</B_Regist>
      <B_Show_InMenu>1</B_Show_InMenu>
      <N_Project>-1</N_Project>
      <C_Const>EDC_Meter</C_Const>
    </Item>
  </dbo.ES_Device_Categories>
  <dbo.ES_Precission_Classes>
    <Item>
      <LINK>7</LINK>
      <N_Project>687783</N_Project>
      <C_Name>2,0</C_Name>
      <C_Const>EPC_20</C_Const>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <LINK>8</LINK>
      <N_Project>687783</N_Project>
      <C_Name>2,5</C_Name>
      <C_Const>EPC_25</C_Const>
    </Item>
  </dbo.ES_Precission_Classes>
</Tables>
```

I've tried a lot of things, deleted them, but here's the way I was hoping for, but I get an error:

```
SET @myDoc.modify('delete /Tables/*[contains(name(), "null")]');
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is deleting 2nd level XML elements under the root (*Tables*) that have in turn *Item* elements without  children.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @myDoc XML =
N'<Tables>
    <dbo.ES_Connection_Modes>
        <Item/>
    </dbo.ES_Connection_Modes>
    <dbo.ES_Device_Categories>
        <Item>
            <LINK>1</LINK>
            <F_Class>1</F_Class>
            <N_Code>1</N_Code>
            <B_Default>1</B_Default>
            <B_Meter>1</B_Meter>
            <B_Tranf>0</B_Tranf>
            <B_Regist>0</B_Regist>
            <B_Show_InMenu>1</B_Show_InMenu>
            <N_Project>-1</N_Project>
            <C_Const>EDC_Meter</C_Const>
        </Item>
    </dbo.ES_Device_Categories>
    <dbo.ES_Indicating_Device_Types>
        <Item/>
    </dbo.ES_Indicating_Device_Types>
    <dbo.ES_Operating_Principles>
        <Item/>
    </dbo.ES_Operating_Principles>
    <dbo.ES_Precission_Classes>
        <Item>
            <LINK>7</LINK>
            <N_Project>687783</N_Project>
            <C_Name>2,0</C_Name>
            <C_Const>EPC_20</C_Const>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <LINK>8</LINK>
            <N_Project>687783</N_Project>
            <C_Name>2,5</C_Name>
            <C_Const>EPC_25</C_Const>
        </Item>
    </dbo.ES_Precission_Classes>
    <dbo.ES_Granularity>
        <Item/>
    </dbo.ES_Granularity>
</Tables>';

SET @myDoc.modify('delete /Tables/*[not(Item/*)]');

-- test
SELECT @myDoc;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What can I read so that I can better understand this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Also, please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0